# why doesn't CSS file work in readthedocs?

Tags: css, documentation, read-the-docs

I have a documentation for my app in `readthedocs` website. And I have a `.css` file that changes side bar appearance. About three month ago this `.css` file worked well, but now it doesn't. Here is the [link](https://robocadsim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
That is how it looked like:
[image]

That is how it looks now:
[image]

The `.css` file:

```css
/* Fixes the size of the RTD flyout */
/* .rst-versions {
    width: 320px !important;
} */

/* Content area color */
.wy-nav-content {
    background: #dddddd;
}

/* Scroll Bar*/
.wy-side-scroll {
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

/* width of the side panel */
.wy-nav-side {
    width: 320px;
}

/* content section full screen */
.wy-nav-content {
   max-width: none; 
}

/* set color of left side bar */
.wy-nav-side,.wy-side-nav-search,.wy-nav-top {
    /*background: #0079c1; /*005eb8 */
   background: #006464;
}

/* Change caption color to be more legible */
.wy-menu > .caption > span.caption-text {
   color: #ffcccc;
   font-size: 20px;
}

/* Change the version color to match caption color */
.wy-side-nav-search>div.version {
   color: #ffcccc;
}

/* Get rid of that ugly yellow highlight color and replace with something more appealing to the eye */
.highlight .hll {
   background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
/* 
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .wy-nav-content-wrap {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .wy-nav-side {
        width: 500px;
    }
} */
```

What could be the reason of this? Thanks!

Comment: Version 1.0 of [`sphinx_rtd_theme`](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme) was released on 2021-09-13. HTML markup, CSS, or JS may have changed, and you will need to adapt your custom style sheet accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I partially confirm what @Steve Piercy says in the comment. The rule `.wy-menu > .caption > span.caption-text {` doesn't work anymore, since the `<p>` that surrounds the `<span class="caption-text">` no longer has a `caption` class. You can check that by comparing [latest](https://robocadsim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with [1.3.4-branch](https://robocadsim.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.4-branch/).

However, as you can see from the build logs ([old](https://readthedocs.org/projects/robocadsim/builds/12992428/), [new](https://readthedocs.org/projects/robocadsim/builds/14742664/)), the problem is not with `sphinx-rtd-theme` (you are using 0.5.0 in both), but the `docutils` version (0.16 in the old build, 0.17 in the new build). You will need to either upgrade your Sphinx version, or downgrade docutils.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! So I just changed ```requirements.txt``` file and added there line ```docutils==0.16``` and now everything is ok!